# backbone js using multiple collection in view

Tags: backbone.js, collections, view

I am quite new in backbone js . I was reading the documentation of backbone and I come up with this idea to use multiple collection in view.
If I have **single view** and I want to use **more than one collection** how can I achieve it?
how can the view understand multiple collection?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you ever need to use multiple collection inside a single view? Backbone's strength is it's modularity, which means you can develop the whole structure of your application by building it's components piece-by-piece. So in normal circumstances one view has one model or collection of models, but it's acceptable and it's often used the case when a collection has multiple views (for example a chat system).

To have multiple collections inside a single view is against backbone's modularity principle. Breaking up views to respond to only one model/collection turns out much more modular and reusable code.

So i suggest to break up your application into smaller pieces and operate on segment level, but if you really need to preserve the current structure you can do something like this:

```
var view = new MyView({
  collection: {
    users: new UsersCollection(),
    organization: new OrganizationCollection()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I just want to learn to use it but I won't I think afterward .